# Adverb oder nachgestelltes Adjektiv?

Tags: adjective, adverb, adjective-ending

Beim Lesen eines Textes von Schopenhauer bin ich über eine mir zu verwirrende Konstruktion gestolpert:

"Übrigens darf es uns nicht wundern, dass auf jene abstruse, spekulative, schwierige und bedenkliche Frage das unmittelbare Selbstbewusstsein keine Antwort aufzuweisen hat. Denn dieses ist ein sehr beschränkter Teil unseres gesamten Bewusstseins, welches, in seinem Innern **dunkel**, mit allen seinen objektiven Erkenntniskräften ganz nach Außen gerichtet ist."

Wie ist denn dieses *dunkel* zu verstehen? Handelt es sich hier einfach um ein nachgestelltes Adjektiv von "Innern", und wenn ja, warum ist es nicht gebeugt worden?, oder eher um ein Adverb vom *gerichtet sein*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Denn [das Selbstbewußtsein] ist ein sehr beschränkter Teil unseres gesamten Bewusstseins, welches, **in seinem Innern dunkel**,  mit allen seinen objektiven Erkenntniskräften ganz nach Außen gerichtet ist.

Zunächst muß man feststellen, daß die hervorgehobene Phrase parenthetisch, also eingeschoben, ist. Zum Verständnis des Satzes ist sie nicht erforderlich und man kann sie weglassen.

*Welches* als Relativpronomen und Subjekt des Relativsatzes bezieht sich auf das Bewußtsein; die eingeschobene Phrase wird ebenso mit Bezug auf *Bewußtsein* interpretiert. Dem Bewußtsein wird die Eigenschaft zugeschrieben, in seinem Innern dunkel zu sein. Die Konstruktion ist also um Subjekt und Verb verkürzt. Man spricht von einer **satzwertigen Adjektivphrase**.

Diese Art von Einschüben ohne Subjekt und ohne explizite Prädikation existiert in verschiedenen Formen. Die traditionelle Terminologie ignoriert das Gemeinsame der Konstruktionen und benennt sie unterschiedlich: als **absoluten Nominativ**, als **absoluten Akkusativ** und als **satzwertige Partizipialkonstruktion**.

> Anja, **von Haus aus Fremdsprachensekretärin,** hat sich im Schnelldurchlauf mit der neuen Umgebung vertraut gemacht und Touristen als Reiseführerin die Sehenswürdigkeiten der Urlaubsregion am Atlantischen Ozean nähergebracht. [1](https://www.giessener-allgemeine.de/kreis-giessen/entschleunigen-haus-meer-13530750.html)
>
> **Die Hände in den Taschen ihrer kniekurzen Hosen** […] schaut sie skeptisch zu Tal. [2](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/kultur/christian-borchert-und-die-ddr-familie-vor-und-nach-dem-fall/25446154.html)
>
> **Den Hut tief ins Gesicht gezogen,** beobachte ich Pfeife paffend die Herde. [3](https://www.badische-zeitung.de/selbstversuch-wie-idyllisch-ist-das-leben-eines-schafhirten--178306946.html)

Es wird behauptet, daß diese Art von Einschüben sich zu einem Nebensatz vervollständigen lassen. Im Beispiel erscheint mir das schwierig. Man muß einen Konnektor finden, den man für passend hält, vielleicht (adversatives oder temporales?) *während*:

> Denn [das Selbstbewußtsein] ist ein sehr beschränkter Teil unseres gesamten Bewusstseins, welches, **während es in seinem Innern dunkel ist**,  mit allen seinen objektiven Erkenntniskräften ganz nach Außen gerichtet ist.

Eventuell ist auch die Behauptung, daß solche Konstruktionen sich immer in einen Nebensatz auflösen lassen, falsch.

Comment: "Es wird behauptet, daß diese Art von Einschüben sich zu einem Nebensatz vervollständigen lassen". Hast du Quellen dazu?

Comment: @Nico Kurz gegoogelt: *um eine Konstruktion als satzwertig bestimmen zu können, muss sie in einen Nebensatz umgeformt werden können* [Duden Fit für das Bachelorstudium](https://shop.duden.de/sites/default/files/bachelor/UebungsaufgabenKapitel4.pdf); die Formulierungen *können durch einen Nebensatz ersetzt werden* unter [canoo](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Form/Partizip.html?MenuId=Sentence623)

Comment: Mir scheint oben ein verschiedener Fall vorzuliegen. In den Beispielen unter http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Form/Partizip.html?MenuId=Sentence623 handelt es sich um Adjektive partizipialen Ursprungs. Das gilt auch für das Beispiel im Duden. Das trifft nicht auf "dunkel" zu. Daher müsste man andere analytische Kriterien finden ...

Answer (score 4):

Es ist eine leicht verkürzte Form, um das *ist* nicht doppelt zu verwenden. Wenn du den Teil mit *Erkenntniskräften* weglässt, lautet der Satz

> (...) Bewusstseins, welches, in seinem Innern dunkel ist.

Comment: Und wie geht der Satz dann weiter? *mit allen seinen ...*?

Answer (score 3):

Ein Adjektiv. Wenn es ein Adverb wäre ("auf eine dunkle Art und Weise"), würde es sich auf "gerichet ist" beziehen, und das Komma müsste wegfallen.

Comment: Du warst um 41 Sekunden schneller...

Comment: Purer Zufall ;-)

Comment: Ein Adjektiv, aber kein nachgestelltes!

Comment: @DavidVogt Ja, mann solte aber auch berücksichtigen, dass die Konstruktion auf einer Weglassung beruht: "in seinem Innern dunkel (ist)". Somit wird das Adjektiv prädikativ verwendet.